# MPXJ: Cant read field values when custom field headers are present in file

Tags: ms-project, mpxj

I'm using MPXJ to read Microsoft Project files (.mpp), but [the current version of MPXJ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpxj/files/) (7.2.1) seems to refuse to read Lookup fields when I change a field to have a different name.

For example, create a new project, show Text1, set it to Lookup, add 0 and 1 to the Lookup list, and rename Text1 to anything ('Test').  Now generate a task and set it's Text1 (Test) to 1.

Now you can't read the 1 in Text1 (task.getText(1) returns null).

We parse many files, some of them are quite large, so it's not possible for me to continually modify our customers' headers, read them in, and then change them back.  Further, I don't see any way to modify them programatically.

Has anyone else found this issue?  Does anyone know how to workaround/fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in MPXJ. I will be committing a fix to the MPXJ repo shortly.

Comment: I've now committed the change which I believe fixes the issue.